# Need some direction

Tags: javascript, object, styles

Just wondering if someone could look at this snippet of code and let me know if I got this right. Trying to loop through the allCells object collection and set the background color to white and run an event handler that runs a changeColor() function when each cell is clicked.  Thanks!

```
window.onload = setPuzzle;

var allCells;

function setPuzzle() {
    var puzzleTable = document.getElementById("puzzleCells");
    var allCells = document.getElementsByName("puzzleTable");

for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    allCells[i].style.backgroundcolor = "white";    
    }

for (var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    allCells[i].onclick = changeColor()
    }

document.getElementById("solution").onclick = showSolution();
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = hideSolution();
document.getElementById("check").onclick = checkSolution();
document.getElementById("uncheck").onclick = uncheckSolution();     
}
```

Comment: the first for loop seems odd, you should have allCells[i].style... I guess

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: I haven't tried to run it yet.  This is the beginning of the program and wanted to make sure that I was somewhat correct.   I edited the code above to include the allCells[i] code.  If I am trying to change all the cells bg color to white do I need the document.getElementsByTagName(allCells)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your first loop

```
allCells[i].document.getElementsByName(allCells)
```

there should be something like

```
allCells = document.getElementsByName( [[ NAME ]] );
```

And

```
document.getElementsByName(allCells)
```

can't work, because *allCells* isn't set to anything.

After you've set allCells to the List of Elements, you can iterate over them like that:

```
allCells[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

And JavaScript is case sensitive so you have to write backgroundColor instead of backgroundcolor.

Update: To assign a function to an event, you have to write

```
.onclick = yourFunction;
```

not

```
.onclick = yourFunction();
```

On the long run it would be even better to use this:

```
.addEventListener("click", yourFunction);
```